A square divided into congruent rectangles
Can a 1*1 unit square divided into congruent rectangles with irrational side lengths?

The answer might seem trivial, but there are two irrational numbers in which both their sum multiple is rational;
Do you have some clear proofs?

My idea was, if we use a horizontal rectangle and a vertical one connected to it(there must be two rectangles like that form unless every rectangle is directed same way), then there will be one corner made by them. To fill that we need another rectangle, and I thought repeating this would give a result like 'one side of the rectangle must be a rational multipled the other side' which can end the problem. However, I could not complete the proof with that idea; I think there are too many cases.

I think the answer is no.

One of the side lengths must be 1 if I understand your question correctly.

No.
There is a well-known theorem that says "If a finite number of rectangles, every one of which has at least one rational side, perfectly tile a big rectangle, then the big rectangle also has at least one rational side".
How is this related, you might ask. Why, let's assume your rectangles are all sized $a\times b$; now stretch (or rather, squeeze) the entire picture by a factor of $a$ in both directions. After you do so, all rectangles have sides of $a^2$ and $ab$ (the latter being inevitably rational), while the square becomes $a\times a$ (which are irrational). A contradiction.
So it goes.

I worried that the problem might not have a simple proof, but this one was beutiful. And for who didn't went into the link, that theorem does not need any complex proof. Thank you so much.

Why $ab$ must be rational?

@RupertRybka Because that's the area of a rectangle which supposedly tiles a unit square.
